# Cant import or require webpack generated file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I used webpack to pack a couple files using this config.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./jstasklib/task.js', './jstasklib/worker.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'app.js',
    library: 'jstasklib'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

If i then start a node terminal and require the file, it just gives me an empty object:

```
node
var foo = require('./dist/app.js');
console.log(foo);
-> {}
```

However, if I toss a `console.log(jstasklib)` at the bottom of app.js and the run `node ./dist/app.js` I get this output which seems like it should allow me to at least import Worker in that earlier example:

```
{default: [Function: Worker]}
```

So what gives?  Is my webpack config wrong?  Whats the proper setup to be able to import things from the webpack generated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're using export default in your app.js file, this isn't set by default. Try setting the output libraryTarget to commonjs2

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

```
output: {
path: __dirname + '/dist',
filename: 'app.js',
library: 'jstasklib',
libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
```